# go through an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I want to increment up where I use a[0].  Something like `a++`. The only other solution I can think of is a switch case or a bunch of if/else if statement, but that seems inefficient. Is this possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
    const char *a[6];    
    a[0]="one";
    a[1]="two";
    a[2]="three";
    a[3]="four";
    a[4]="five";
    a[5]="six";

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("This old man, he played %s\nHe played knick-knack on my thumb\nKnick-knack paddywhack, give your dog a bone\nThis old man came rolling home\n\n", a[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
printf(..., a[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `a[i]`.

However that's a very basic question, I'd suggest you to take a look at some tutorial in internet before asking.

Comment: thank you. Yes, being so new to this I didn't even know how to search for it. but i will keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `a[i]` inside the loop to access the i<sup>th</sup> element.

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    printf("%s\n", a[i]);
```

If you ever have need to increment a pointer inside a loop, you can do it like this:

```
const char **p=a;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    printf("%s\n", *p++);
```

Personally, I would use `a[i]`.